# react-testing-library getAll and then filter to find an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a page which renders a list of custom `checkbox`es. 
Each `checkbox` looks like this.

```
<div
  className="checkbox"
  role="checkbox"
  onClick={onClick}
  onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
  aria-checked={getState().checked}
  tabIndex={0}
>
  {getState().checked ? (
    <span className="checkbox__icon checkbox__selected">
      <Icon src="/icons/check-box-selected.svg" alt="checkbox selected" />
    </span>
  ) : (
    <span className="checkbox__icon">
      <Icon src="/icons/check-box-empty.svg" alt="checkbox not selected" />
    </span>
  )}
  <span className="checkbox__label">{label}</span>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to find a particular `checkbox` while testing.
The `checkbox`es differ in their labels (currently implemented using `span` and key/click handlers).

I want to test when the label is clicked, the image should change.

Let's say user clicked on `checkbox1` with label "checkbox1", the image should change from "checkbox selected" to "checkbox not selected"

I am facing issues while trying to get reference to a `checkbox` with a particular label.

If i do `getByText("checkbox1")` , it returns me the `span` element, and I don't have a reference to the actual `checkbox` to assert whether the image has changed.

My workaround for now is to `getAllByRole` and then `filter(item => item.textContext === "checkbox1")` and then `queryByAltText`.

Is there a better approach to test this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best way, in my opinion, will be to give the checkbox div an id prop with the label var and just do getElementByID.

But if you get the span like you say you can always do `.parentElement` and get the checkbox div.

You can also use `.closest("div.checkbox");` on the span and it will look for the closest div with class checkbox.

Comment: .parentElement would likely make the test fragile, as i can nest the span further without changing anything for the user.

Comment: The id approach or the testid approach works, but that is my last resort, as I don't want to add something just for testing purpose

Comment: well, you can use .closest("div"); as well, it will give you the nearest div.

Comment: .closest would also be fragile, it is easy to change the structure of the component without the user even seeing a difference. I don't think I would want my tests to be broken in that case.